# GIT command for Clone OR Update

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm migrating to GIT from another source code versioning tool and the workflow is a bit different.

With the old tool I had a build that was automatically started everytime a developer made any change in the remote depot. This build was meant to be fast so did not remove the source code and got it again from the depot. Instead I made an update of the code in the disk with the changes in the remote server.

As far as I known this is a `pull` in GIT. But to be able to make a pull I need to make a `clone` before. But for the first build or if for any reason I need to remove the source code I really need a `clone` of the depot.

So may question is...is there any GIT command to perform a clone if there is nothing in the disk but just an update (pull) if I just need to update the current source code???

Thanks.

Comment: No, but you should be able to bake that into your build script, if the .git folder exists, pull, otherwise, clone. Also, please read through your question, as it seems it is missing pieces of text. "As far as I know this is a in GIT". A what now?

Comment: Edited. Thanks I was using words into <> and it seems I cannot. Sure I can implement it myself but wondering if there is such a command in GIT.

Comment: No, there's nothing built into git for this.

Answer (score 3):

Create an alias like in the following example:

```
alias git-clone-pull='if [[ -d .git ]]; then git pull; else git clone GIT-SERVER-REPOSITORY; fi'
```

If you execute git-clone-pull inside a Git repository it'll execute the "git pull" command, otherwise it'll execute the "git clone" one.

Comment: One suggested modification for this alias: tell git clone to put contents into the current working directory by specifying the path (absolute or relative, whichever) after the server URL. (Something like `git clone SERVER_URL .` or `git clone SERVER_URL /path/to/folder` should work.) Otherwise, `git clone` will put the new copy in a subfolder of the current working directory, where future git-clone-pull runs won't see it.